# Hiding/Showing extra content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I havent used Javascript in a while and I have almost forgotten it all but I would like to be reminded how to show and hide html div boxs to display hidden content by clicking on a text or such.

In this case I would like to have a hidden box filled with login information while the ahref link will be the indicator to tell the loginbox to appear or disappear and by knowing this I could easily apply it to the register area.

I would like to know how to do this or a pop up box sort of thing.

This is what I have so far:
Could anyone help me with this now. I can't seem to get it work.

The toggle is

```
<a href="#" onclick="showStuff('signup'); return false;"> Login</a>
```

Showing content

```
<div class="signup" style="display: none;">
<p> test </p>
</div>
```

Javascript is
    
    function showStuff(signup) {
        document.getElementById('signup').style.display = 'block';
    }

Why won't this work

Comment: `document.getElementById('element-id').style.display = 'none';`
and
`document.getElementById('element-id').style.display = 'block|inline|etc';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript hide/show element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: I added more information..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue with your code is that your div has a class as 'signup' not an id.
try:

```
<div id="signup" style="display: none;">
<p> test </p>
</div>
```

See this jsfiddle for a working example with an additional fix to how your function works.
http://jsfiddle.net/aUQ6B/

**Original Answer:**

See: [javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Code to make note of is the following:

```
document.getElementById('myid').style.display
```

Setting this to 'none' hides the element.
Setting it to 'block, 'inline' or whatever the original value was will show the element.