# echo message onto next page for 5 seconds/timeout message?

Tags: php, html, session

i currently have my site configured so that when a user logs in they are navigated to the home page of my site and they get a welcome message within a session. the bit im having trouble with is finding a way to timeout or close this message or chage the css settings to display:none after 3 seconds.

Can someone please show me how i could add a time out function onto this, heres what i got so far, thanks.

User logs in using html login form, this submits and goes to login.php:

inside login.php i have this:

```
<?php
if (logged_in()) 
{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\">
<h1>Login You In Securely</h1></div>"; 
header("Location:home.php");

}
?>
```

Then inside home.php i have this:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_message'] ))
   echo $_SESSION['login_message'];
    unset($_SESSION['login_message']) ;

?>
```

how can i add a 3 second rule to this so that it only shows for 3 seconds thanks.

Comment: Why to use PHP for this functionality. Use JQUERY setTimeout

`setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);`

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'none';
}, 3000);
```

[javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery,

```
$(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
       $("#message").hide('slow');
   }, 3000);
});
```