# JavaScript hide element function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where the user can select a generic `auto-population` based on checking a radio button.  When the user checks the `auto-populate` radio button, the fields are auto populated with the data and then the fields become `disabled`.

In this first part of the function, I pass the auto-filled data:

```
            $('#myOptions').click(function()
            $('#value1').val("Auto-filled data");
            $('#Value2').val("Auto-filled data");                
            $('#Value3').val("Auto-filled data");
```

In this second part, I am disabling the html inputs

```
            // now i am disabling the html inputs:
            $('#Value4').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#Value5').prop("disabled", true);                
            $('#value6').prop("disabled", true);
```

Suppose I have another field with an ID of "Value7" in the form, that I would like to hide from the user interface as part of this function.

How can I hide the "Value7" input upon function triggering? I appreciate the help, I am very new to JavaScript, though I find it very exciting!

Comment: Actually i don't understand what you trying to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jquery:

To hide

```
jQuery('#Value7').hide() or jQuery('#Value7').css("display","none")
```

To show the element back

```
jQuery('#Value7').show() or jQuery('#Value7').css("display","block")
```

or pure js:

[javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: Awesome, I like how JQuery simplifies it so that I can just call the .hide() method. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this javascript:**

**if you want disable:**

```
document.getElementById('#Value7').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

**if you want enable:**

```
document.getElementById('#Value7').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

**if you want to hide :**

```
document.getElementById('#Value7').css("display","none");
```

**if you want to show:**

```
document.getElementById('#Value7').css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting what are you trying to ask actualy .
Let me know if this helps -

$("Value7").hide()