# Is it possible to show a division in html whenever required ? if yes, how to enable and disable it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a screen which should be shown based on only certain conditions. Is it possible to put the entire screen in a division and show it whenever needed ? If yes, how to enable or disable it ? By default is it enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean - How do you show and hide HTML elements using JavaScript? then I suggest that you look in to jQuery, particularly [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Otherwise plain JavaScript can be used, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element).

If this doesn't answer your question then you might need to make your question a little clearer.