# How to open Custom pop on click of Button?

Tags: javascript

I am having a scenario when I am clicking on a button then one pop-up must be opened asking "Do you want to perform this operation". There are two button OK and Cancel. And on pressing any of there button control must go i controller and do required task.

After doing google, I find one way using windows.open but i cannot apply my css on this and there is no particular url for this. So this did not worked.

I have tried that when the page load a div having this data should hide and after clicking it must shown but this is not giving felling of popup.

```
<body onload="hide()">
    <center>
        <script>
            function hide() {
                document.getElementById("show").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }

            function show() {
                document.getElementById("show").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        </script>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="get">
                <div id="show">Demo</div>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a id="dialog-link" href="">
                            <button type="button" value="Show Pop up"
                                    onclick="show()">Click</button>
                        </a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: In a nutshell, you want to open something like bootstrap modal window with some information yes?

Comment: Yes and perform operation on clicking button

Comment: Please remove the Java tag since JavaScript has absolutely nothing to do with Java.

Comment: What modern tutorial told you to use a `<center>` tag? I want to know so I can strangle them.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:
1. Add style "display:none", that will hide your element in DOM.
2. Change that attribute using JS.

```
<body onload="hide()">
    <center>
        <script>
            function hide() {
            document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'none';
            }

            function show() {
                document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'block';
                            }
        </script>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="get">
                <div id="show" style="display: none;">Demo</div>
                <table>
                     <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a id="dialog-link" href=""><button type="button"
                                    value="Show Pop up" onclick="show()">Click</button></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Here is a similar topic:
[javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

If you want something more than a confirm modal, something with more css, I would go into bootstrap, because creating a modal window from scratch can be sometimes hard, and bootstrap gives you free API for that. But it will require jQuery in your app.

Comment: But if you want this element to behave like a confirm popup, alert or bootstrap modal, you need to work on your css. My snipplet will simple show/hide an element, but it has no css classes:)

Comment: I am using jquery modal box as of now

Comment: When i am making same application for modal box then it is working but when i am merging this logic with my existing code then it is falling.    Any other way

Answer (score 0):

i think you need confirmation box:

```
     function show() {
 confirm("do your operation!");
}
```

Comment: No i want customized dialog box

Comment: visit here:http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?75527-Creating-a-custom-prompt-dialog-box-to-retrieve-value-of-text-field-amp-store-as-a-var