# (JavaScript / HTML) How to change display in style attribute on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, onclick

I'm a beginner programmer and I wanted to have an image loaded but not displayed:

`<img src="someImage.png" class="mainImage" id="image1" style="display:none"/>`

I want to add a button which would then remove/change the image display from none to make it visible, so that each image could be displayed by clicking on a button.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element

Comment: Set the *style.display* property to `''` (empty string).

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle the element's display between *block* and *""* (empty string). So you might have a button like:

```
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('image1')">Image 1</button>
```

And a *toggleDisplay* function like:

```
function toggleDisplay(id) { 
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el && el.style) {
    el.style.display = el.style.display != 'none'? 'none' : '';
  } 
}
```

Toggling between *none* and "" (empty string) allows the element to return to its default or inherited value and the function becomes generic.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#image1").show();
});
```

Or

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
     $("#image1").css("display", "block");
 });
```

Comment: That requires jQuery (I assume...) The question isn't tagged for nor does it mention jquery.

Comment: @ChadW: didn't know that I just assumed he would be interested in jQuery solution :-/