# Remove Facebook Log-in Button after a successful log in

Tags: javascript, facebook

Im trying to create a login/logout mechanism using Facebook. So far I've managed to edit the default Javascript SDK (with basic JS knowledge) to only display the logout link if the user is logged in. However the Login Button persists regardless of whether the user is logged in or not. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '1467517133547158',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
      document.getElementById('logout-button').innerHTML =
          '<span id="fbLogout" onclick="fbLogout()"><a href="#"><span class="fb_button_text">Logout</span></a></span>';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

<div id="logout-button"></div>

<script>
function fbLogout() {
        FB.logout(function (response) {
            //Do what ever you want here when logged out like reloading the page
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't "edit the ... Javascript SDK," that will result in problems if you ever want to use it with other peoples' work. I think you meant to say "edit the Javascript code."

Comment: Also, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. Removing the logout div altogether I added the autologoutlink="true" to the login button (removing the div from login also):

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys using the above answer i created a solution:

I added the following line to the testAPI() function:

```
document.getElementById('login-button').style.display = 'none';
```

Also I embedded the login button into a div:

```
<div id="login-button">
    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button>
</div>
```