# Show\Hide html element - pros and cons to each approach

Tags: jquery, css, hide, element, show

What are the pros and cons of each?

change the element style directly:

```
$('#element_to_hide').hide(); // when we want to hide
$('#element_to_hide').show(); // when we want to show
```

adding\removing class:

```
.hidden {display:none}
$('#element_to_hide').addClass('hidden');// when we want to hide
$('#element_to_hide').removeClass('hidden'); // when we want to show
```

Are there other methods, and if so, what are their pros and cons?

Comment: easiest way is to use .toggle();

Comment: I don't know the effects of hide/show/hidden, but I always use: $("#element_to_hide").css("display", "none");

Comment: `$('#element_to_hide').toggle()`

Comment: Updated question to allow for non opinion based answers.

Comment: Rewrote my answer. It is more robust now and includes examples.

Comment: Sorry @Ofir, I tried to save this question, but it seems that it will not be reopened. Because of this I moved my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element/

Answer (score 1):

The hide and show functions from jquery is better because it does not just change the display. Lets say your display is inline-block, you will have to hardcode inline-block if you want your element visible again. If you just use hide and show it will change back to what it was before.

It is easier to read as well if someone else is going to work on your code.

Comment: Indeed. I guess I never change the display other than hiding and unhiding.

Comment: add\remove class also doesn't change the display, it is just add or remove the class.

Comment: Yeah I realized it too after writing the post, but I still stand by what I say, I feel hide and show is better.

Comment: add\remove class doesn't change the display, but it doesn't always work to hide stuff. Check out my revamped answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better are `addClass()` and `removeClass()` (and `toggleClass()`). Better, because it doesn't put inline styles to the DOM, so you can do whatever you want with this class in CSS.

Comment: This doesn't always work. Check out my revamped answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following are several different approaches and the pros and cons of each.

-

#### Changing display using addClass()/removeClass()

While setting up the example for this one, I actually ran into some flaws on this method that make it very very unreliable.

Css/Javascript:

```
.hidden {display:none}
$("#element_to_hide").addClass("hidden");  // To hide
$("#element_to_hide").removeClass("hidden");  // To unhide
```

Pros:

- It hides....sometimes. Refer to p1 on the example.
- After unhiding, it will return back to using the previous display value....sometimes. Refer to p1 on the example.
- If you want to grab all hidden objects, you just need to do `$(".hidden")`.

Cons:

- Does not hide if the display value was set directly on the html. Refer to p2 on the example.
- Does not hide if the display is set in javascript using css(). Refer to p3 on the example.
- Slightly more code because you have to define a css attribute.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/476oha8t/8/

-

#### Changing display using toggle()

Javascript:

```
$("element_to_hide").toggle();  // To hide and to unhide
```

Pros:

- Always works.
- Allows you to not have to worry about which state it was prior to switching. The obvious use for this is for a....toggle button.
- Short and simple.

Cons:

- If you need to know which state it is switching to in order to do something not directly related, you will have to add more code (an if statement) to find out which state it is in.
- Similar to the previous con, if you want to run a set of instructions that contains the toggle() for the purpose of hiding, but you don't know if it is already hidden, you have to add a check (an if statement) to find out first and if it is already hidden, then skip. Refer to p1 of the example.
- Related to the previous 2 cons, using toggle() for something that is specifically hiding or specifically showing, can be confusing to others reading your code as they do not know which way they will toggle.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cxcawkyk/1/

-

#### Changing display using hide()/show()

Javascript:

```
$("#element_to_hide").hide();  // To hide
$("#element_to_hide").show();  // To show
```

Pros:

- Always works.
- After unhiding, it will return back to using the previous display value.
- You will always know which state you are swapping to so you:

  1. don't need to add if statements to check visibility before changing states if the state matters.
  2. won't confuse others reading your code as to which state you are switching to if, if the state matters.
- Intuitive.

Cons:

- If you want to imitate a toggle, you will have to check the state first and then switch to the other state. Use toggle() instead for these. Refer to p2 of the example.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/k0ukhmfL/

-

#### Changing display using css()

This method I do not recommend to use, but it is added for completeness.

Javascript:

```
$("#element_to_hide").css("display", "none");  // To hide
$("#element_to_hide").css("display", "");  // To unhide
```

Pros:

- Hides and unhides. That's about it.

Cons:

- If you use the "display" attribute for something else, you will have to hardcode the value of what it was prior to hiding. So if you had "inline", you would have to do `$("#element_to_hid").css("display", "inline");` otherwise it will default back to "block" or whatever else that it will be forced into.
- Lends itself to typos.

Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/4chd6e5r/1/

---

TL;DR. I consider the best approach to be `Changing display using hide()/show()` unless you specifically need it to be a toggle.

Comment: jQuery hide and show *does* restore the display setting. What test are you using that indicates otherwise?

Comment: Hmmm. It appears the test I did was invalid. I apologize for that, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Alohci. I have revamped my answer to detail everything.

Comment: One thing to note for future reference. CSS3 has a proposal for a [box-suppress](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box-suppress) property, the purpose of which is to solve this issue without need for  complex save and restore JS.  It's still early days for it though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Gimby. I just want to know one thing. Why did you replace the "." with "-"? Just curious.

Comment: @Macainian meta is a better place for that question. Basically I removed the dots entirely as they are not a condoned formatting style, but then after the fact agreed that the extra spacing really does help. But dots have a really specific purpose: to be the end of a sentence. Dashes on the other hand generally act as a separator. Hence my choice to use those.

Comment: Ah I see. As for why I posted here, I saw this here before I saw you mention your change in meta. Just a bad order of actions.