# How to display an image only if a JS variable is true?

Tags: javascript, html

Just started learning HTML, and I came across a simple problem which I couldn't find the answer to. I know that I can use the line `<img src ="link to src"/>` to display an image. I also know I can used the `<script> </script>` tags to hold javascript code. My question is, how can I only display the img if a variable in my script is equal to true?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <TITLE>Img Tester</TITLE>
    <BODY> 
       <h1>Image:</h1>
       <img src ="link to src"/>  <!--only display this if the variable c == true in the script--> 

    </BODY>
    <SCRIPT>
        var c = confirm("Display Image?");
            if(c== true) {
               //do something here that displays image? 
            }
    </SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd set the default style of the image with `id="img1"` to hidden. Both `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` are similar however visibility takes up space.

Please take a look at the snippet below. If you press ok, you will see the image of the dragon. If you press cancel, it won't appear.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("img1");
var c = confirm("Display Image?");
if (c) {
  image.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#img1 {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image:</h1>
<img id="img1" src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/df02649d-894e-4b82-94da-cd10dd2449a0/7833c7a7-6301-446b-8fbc-ed948aaaa0be.jpg"/>
```

A few pointers

1. Tag names should be in lowercase, not uppercase
2. Instead of `if(c == true)`, use the equivalent `if (c)`

Comment: Great thanks. This and @gurvinder372 both seem like good ways. Unfourtunetly I can only accept one and he was about 30 seconds before you. However, I did +1 you.

Comment: That's understandable. I will edit this answer to improve it though for future readers

Comment: @AshwinGupta actually Richard's solution is better. Only change I would make is using display:none rather than visibility

Comment: @gurvinder372 oh okay. Well then I guess I'll accept his. Thank you for your honesty! I still +1 you though for the quick/valid response. Also, can I do this: `<img visibility: hidden, src ="link to src"/>` ?

Comment: `display:none` ? In my applications, I usually always use `visibility:hidden`. Should I change it to `display:none`?

Comment: @AshwinGupta `<img style='visibility: hidden' src ="link to src"/>`

Comment: @RichardHamilton thanks for the pointers too. As for 1, I'll keep note of that. 2, I just wanted to be safe since I didn't know if JS had that shorthand, normally I'd do that.

Comment: Yes, change it to `display:none` since then it won't take any space. `Visibility:visible` takes space and then hide the same but still keeps the space.

Comment: Alright got it working! @gurvinder372 thanks for your help also.

Answer (score 2):

Give an id to that image and hide the element with that id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <TITLE>Img Tester</TITLE>

    <BODY> 
       <h1>Image:</h1>
       <img  style="display:none" id="img1" src ="link to src"/>  <!--only display this if the variable c == true in the script--> 

    </BODY>
    <SCRIPT>
        var c = confirm("Display Image?");
            if(c== true) {
               document.getElementById( "img1" ).style.display = "inline"; 
            }
    </SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

Observe two changes in the code

- `Id` attribute has been given to the image element and its display property is set to `none`
- In the `if` section, a line has been added to hide the image using that id

  document.getElementById( "img1" ).style.display = "inline";

by setting its `display` property to `'inline'`.

Comment: Thank you. Will accept this one. Didn't realize that there were "fields" to html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<HTML>
    <TITLE>Img Tester</TITLE>
    <BODY> 
       <h1>Image:</h1>
       <img id="img"/>
    </BODY>
    <SCRIPT>
        var c = confirm("Display Image?");
            if(c== true) {
               document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src","1.jpg"); 
            }
    </SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, doesn't seem like this has anything the other two didn't however.

Answer (score 0):

Use div for this as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "display">
    <h1>Image:</h1>
    <img src ="link to src"/>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('display').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var c = confirm("Display Image?");
    if(c== true) {
       //do something here that displays image? 
       document.getElementById('display').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use classes for this task...

```
<img id="image-1" class="myimage" />
```

In your styles you should hide the image

```
.myimage {
    display: none;
}
```

Also you need another class to show your image

```
.myimage-show {
    display: block;
}
```

Now you need set *myimage-show* class to show your image

```
 <script>
    var c = confirm("Display Image?");
    if(c== true) {
       document.getElementById('image-1').classList.add('myimage-show'); 
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` will download the image even if the user clicks cancel. Here's another approach to download the image ONLY if the user clicks OK

```
<h1>Image:</h1>
<div id="myImg"></div>

</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
    var c = confirm("Display Image?");
    if(c== true) {
        document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML='<img src="img_src" />';
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

You can replace the `div` with `p` or whatever you like.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I will look into this.