# displaying html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please am a newbie in programming, I really need your help in this. Please how can I hide an HTML table then display it with a button  using.JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript hide/show element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score 1):

Use document.querySelector to get the elements and the `hidden` attribute to show and hide the table. Use an event listener and listen for the `click` event on the button:

```js
var table = document.querySelector("table");
table.hidden = true;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  table.hidden = false;
});
```

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Rain</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>50 mm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>21 mm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5 mm</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called jQuery to do this extremely easily.

- In your `<head>`, put `<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js></script>`
- Give your `<table>` an id, like this: `<table id="myTable">`
- Add one button like this: `<button onclick="$('#myTable').hide();">Hide</button>`
- And another like this: `<button onclick="$('#myTable').show();">Show</button>`

This will allow you to toggle the table's visibility.

I started writing this before @metarmask posted - his/her answer is much better, so you should probably take his/her advice.