# Show / hide element on mouse click in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, d3.js

I am trying to make the box appear when you click a node and then disappear if you click off of it. Right now it appears from the get go and it doesn't go away when you click off. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajaisle/nw7g157c/8/)

I tried to I am assuming the edit goes somewhere in here but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've also checked the other related questions but they have different specific issues.

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(data.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
 .on("click", function(d) {
  text = "Generic Text Here: " + d.name;
      d3.selectAll(".infobox")  
    //.append("rect")
    //.attr("x", 70)
    //.attr("y", 5)
    //.attr("height", 100)
    //.attr("width", 200) 
    //.select("text")
    .select("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", text) 
    .selectAll("text").text(text)})  
  .call(force.drag);
```

Thank you thank you

Comment: you want to toggle the box on click of node ?

Comment: Correct. And I want it to start off but then show up when a node is clicked/disappear again when user clicks off

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apart from hide/show I guess you also need to handle scenario where one node clicked and box shown now clicking on another node then the box should be visible with that node data

```
  if(this.getAttribute("ind") == prev && document.getElementById("plot").style.display == 'block'){
        document.getElementById("plot").style.display = 'none';
    }else{
    document.getElementById("plot").style.display = 'block';}
    prev = i;
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nw7g157c/9/

Comment: Brilliant! That's a big step forward, thank you! Do you know how to do the hide/show? Apologies if it is on that new fiddle. I'm on my phone so it may be acting weird.

Comment: @AlyssaJaisle yes thats on the fiddle

Comment: ah, I see. It clicks back off when you click the node again. Is there a way to hide it when you click in the background? My end goal is to have the box overlaying the nodes. The user will need to be able to click an arbitrary place on the screen/layout area for it to click off.  Thanks so much for your help this far. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so so much for your time. Opening my computer back up to figure out how to mark this as answered. Then I can rest happy.

Answer (score 0):

Seems similar to this question: [javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

If you prefer not to use jQuery (d3.js can do some of the same things anyways- you know your app best):

```
///Show. Put in your "mouseout" callback
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
//Hide. Put in your callback in .on("click", ....
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
```

The "id" corresponds to your box.
Hope that helps!

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/nw7g157c/19/

I had to do a bit of hacking around, but I used the above suggestion to add this:

```
document.documentElement.onclick = function(e) {
  let evt = e || window.event, // IE...
      target = evt.target || evt.srcElement // IE again...

  if (target.nodeName !== 'circle') { //show the plot box if not a circle:
      document.getElementById('plot').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

and this in your on("click"...)

```
document.getElementById('plot').style.display = 'none';
```

Please up vote as it will feed my children