# Html & Javascript hiding existing table cells without destroying them

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, hidden

I've got the jscript working that adds row to the page on click, what I need to do now is to hide the bottom most cell each time the remove button is clicked, BUT the cell can't be destroyed because if cells are added later, any previously populated cell has to show back up untouched. My plan was that I could just put the body's child nodes into an array, start at the end on the array and work toward the front and change the first visible node that I come across to hidden and then return, seemingly this would do what I need done, but for some reason my function is producing any result....at all, no errors, no infinite loops, no nothing. I'll post my code below. The issue is, unless there's a careless mistake somewhere, in the `removeFields()` function. I'm stumped.

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: #2a334d;
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container{
  padding:45px;
  width:80%;
  color:#e8491d;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: medium;
  border:solid;
  min-height: none;
}
table{
  align-content: center;
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding-left: 175px;
}
.shown{
  visibility: visible;
}
.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
footer{
  padding:10px;
  margin-top:50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    <title>assignment 3</title>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <div class="container">
      <table id="test" class="centered">
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <tr id="table" class="shown">
          <th><a id="number">1</a></th>
          <th><input id="text" onkeyup="countLength()"></input></th>
          <th><span id="length">0</span></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <footer>
        <tr>
          <button class="addElement" onclick="addField('table')">add</button>
          <button class="removeElement" onclick="removeField()">remove</button>
          <button class="sortElements" onclick="sortFields()">sort</button>
        </tr>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var fieldCount = 1;

function countLength(){
  for(i= 0; i< fieldCount; i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value.length;
  }
}

function addField(){
  var array = document.body.childNodes;
  for(i = 0; i< array.length ; i++){
    if(array[i].className == "hidden"){
      array[i].className = 'shown';
      return;
    }
  }
  var lastTr = document.getElementById("table");
  var cloneTr = lastTr.cloneNode(true);

  cloneTr.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML = fieldCount+1;
  cloneTr.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = '';
  cloneTr.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 0;
  document.getElementById("test").append(cloneTr);
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[fieldCount].addEventListener("keyup", countLength());
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[fieldCount].className = "shown";

  fieldCount++;
  }

  function removeField(){
    var array = document.body.childNodes;

    for(var tmp = array.length-1; tmp>=0 ; tmp--){
      if(array[tmp].className == "shown"){
        array[tmp].className = 'hidden';
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Too much code... please give a live example on jsfiddle or so... if you want to hide one cell, you should use `visibility:hidden;` so the table would stay the way it was formatted before

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element

Comment: `document.body.childNodes` is `[<div class="container">]`. Use `document.querySelectorAll('.shown')` instead.

Comment: Also, instead of `if(array[tmp].className == "shown")` use `if(array[tmp].classList.contains('shown'))`. `if(array[tmp].className == "shown")` can be easily broken.

Comment: There's no longer anything named "JScript"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for determining which cell should be hidden is not working.  The line `array[tmp].className == "shown"` is never returning true, since `array[tmp].className` has a value of `undefined` on each instance of the loop, except when looking at the div.

Also, it looks like `document.body.childNodes` is only getting the direct descendants of the `body` elements, not all descendants, so it's never seeing the `tr` elements, which is most likely the reason it's not working.

To address this, you want to loop over the child elements of your table instead, like this:

`var table = document.getElementById("test");
var array = table.childNodes;`

And in your CSS, use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

Incidentally, each `tr` element has the same `id` value.  `id` should be unique within a page.

Comment: thanks man, i never wouold have gotten that. new to html and script