# According panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

When open my file setup panel is open. It's showing `style="display:block"`. When I change it to `display:none;`, it closes the setup panel.

Please tell me how to replace  `display:block` to `display:none;`.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: Hi, When i am used "display:none !important;" menu not opening

Comment: if you share you code with us it will be helpful to understand the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand:

```
element.style{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, When i am used "display:none !important;" menu not opening

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change its display on click of something (say a button with id 'btn'), you the following code:

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    if($('.child_menu').css('display') == 'none'){ 
       $('.child_menu').show(); 
    } else { 
       $('.child_menu').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
$('.child_menu').css("display", "none");
$('.child_menu').css("display", "block");
```

instead of show() and hide().