# AJAX, JS - hide element if number of post is equal to zero

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my Django project I want the table head will be hide if at my Database with posts is empty.
Can you give advance how I should it implement at my project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you receive the response from the ajax call...with plain javascript you can check if the response is empty or null and then use

`document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";`
now if you want to again show the header then use after you receive the response

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
```

In this case, space is allocated on the page
[Check this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your rendering logic.

First store both button markup and table markup in an each variable. 
Eg: **renderTable** and **renderButton**

Then check for length of your ajax response result array. Display the table or button element with conditional operator as below:

```
var renderTable = `<table><thead>...</thead><tbody>...</tbody></table>`;
var renderButton = `<button>Create Table</button>`;
results.length > 0 ? renderTable : renderButton;
```