# How to hide an element of list in c# from displaying in frontage?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, autocomplete

I have a web method which retrieve data from database in list:

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetRequesters(string prefixText)
    {

        ClsTikets obj = new ClsTikets();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringTYC"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select RQID,RQ_Code, Name,Email,Phone,location from tbl_Requester where Name like @SearchText + '%'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            List<string> patients = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendFormat(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString() + "," + dt.Rows[i]["location"].ToString() + "," + dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString() + ","+dt.Rows[i]["RQID"].ToString() + " ");
                patients.Add(sb.ToString());
            }
            return patients;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Now I am handling the front end like this:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtReqName" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtReqName_TextChanged" Style="margin-left: -6px;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
                 OnClientShown="ShowOptions"
                 ServiceMethod="GetRequesters"
                 ServicePath="default2.aspx"
                 MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                 CompletionInterval="0"
                 EnableCaching="True"
                 CompletionSetCount="10"
                 TargetControlID="txtReqName"
                 FirstRowSelected="True">
             </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtReqName" />
         </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click that text-box  Name, location, Email and **RQID** are visible then we can select any one of them. But I don't want to display RQID here.
I can do this by just not appending the RQID into that list.
However in `txtReqName_TextChanged` method I need RQID. Can we do this through JavaScript? I'm not sure. Or any other way to do using `AutoCompleteExtender`.

This is my `txtReqName_TextChanged` method:

```
protected void txtReqName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtReqName.Text != "")
        {
            if (txtReqName.Text != "")
            {
                string[] RQName = txtReqName.Text.Split(',');
                obj.Requster_Code = RQName[3];
                obj.ReqName = RQName[0].ToString();
                obj.Email = RQName[2].ToString();
                DataSet ds = Ticket.Get_ClientInfo(obj);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    txtSoldto.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["soldto"].ToString();
                    txtShipToCode.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShipToCode"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I do that? It may be simple to you. Any help or suggestion would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what control is `RQID ` in your code?

Comment: @MrMins It is primary key column of a table tbl_Requester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me. Here's the JavaScript code to achieve this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowOptions(s, e) {
            $("#AutoCompleteExtender1_completionListElem li").each(function (i) {
                var result = $(this).text();
                var array = result.split(',');
                array.splice(3, 1);
                var result1 = array.join(',');
                $(this).text(result1);
            });
        }
</script>
```

And the `Web Method` is like this(adding the `contextKey`)

```
 [WebMethod]
        public  List<string> GetRequesters(string prefixText,int contextKey)
        {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DataStore;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select RQID,RQ_Code, Name,Email,Phone,location from tbl_Requester where Name like @SearchText + '%'", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                List<string> patients = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendFormat(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString() + "," + dt.Rows[i]["location"].ToString() + "," + dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString() + "," + dt.Rows[i]["RQID"].ToString() + " ");
                    patients.Add(sb.ToString());
                }
                return patients;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can add some hidden attribute to the column on JS time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Can you little elaborate? Any Sample Code?

Comment: Sure, something like this answer should work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243000/5775048 ,  and you can use jQuery as well : http://api.jquery.com/hide/.