# How to change <div> into <input> by onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<p>`a certain text`</p>`
I want by ***onClick*** to changes this into a `<input value="certain text">`,
so it can be edited.

All the solutions I found were clicking on a button. I want the text hides and the input-field appears instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element

Comment: Well, probably handling the `click` event and then hiding the `div` and showing the `input`, I guess?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the original text between the <p> tags and add it as the initial value of the input, or just want to have an input tag with an empty string as the initial value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: Instead of a button why can't you assign an onclick function to the <p> itself?

Comment: The possible value of the button to edit is that it will be clear to the user what he is doing; Assuming your application is to place this in the wild on a web page with users not familiar with the application. Clearly, if this is back office the fewer keystrokes for the operators the better.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what  you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function makeInput(e) {
   e.innerHTML = '<input value="'+e.innerText+'">';
}
```

```html
<p onclick="makeInput(this)">a certain value</p>
```

A possible alternative is to just make the content of the p tag editable and use javascript to submit the information without using a input tag.

```html
<p contenteditable="true">This is an editable paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Click to Edit, click away when done editing.

HTML:

```
<div class="editable">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Nullam dapibus porttitor sem, et tristique neque vehicula eu. 
   Nulla porta ex semper sapien luctus bibendum. Donec et congue nisi
</div>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  min-height: 120px
}
```

JS:

```
var eventHandler = function(e){e.preventDefault(); editDiv(this);};
document.querySelector('.editable').addEventListener("click", eventHandler);

function editDiv(div){
  var text = div.innerText,
      textarea = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
  textarea.value = text;

  div.innerHTML = "";
  div.append(textarea);
    textarea.focus();
  textarea.addEventListener("focusout", function(e){
    finishEditDiv(div);
  });

  div.removeEventListener("click", eventHandler);

}

function finishEditDiv(div){
  //handle your data saving here
  var text = div.querySelector('textarea').value;
  div.innerHTML = text;
  document.querySelector('.editable').addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the `onClick`to the p tag.

Create an hidden input.

On click hide the current p, and get the input associated to that p, then display it.

```js
function onClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#p-input').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p onClick="onClick(event)">Clickable text</p>
  <input id="p-input" style="display:none;" type="text" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use input element only. Use a disabled input with a styling of your choice ( grayish background for example ).
Use onClick event to set the input to active and change its style ( no background ).

Worked pretty good for me.