# CSS is not changing display value after js function changes it

Tags: css

Referring to the example code below.
CSS is not changing the display value after the js function changes it.

Expected example behaviors:

- narrowing window hides "nav display"
- widening window displays "nav display"
- clicking "toggleNav" toggles visibility of "nav display"

Unexpected example behaviors:

- clicking "toggleNav" disables the effect of window width

```js
 /* toggle between showing and hiding nav when the user clicks on toggleNav */
 function toggleNav() {
     var x = document.getElementById("nav");
     if (x.style.display === "block") {
         x.style.display = "none";
     } else {
         x.style.display = "block";
     }
 }
```

```css
 #nav {display: block; } /* display is not restored after js function */

 /* narrow window */
 @media screen and (max-width: 70rem) {
     #nav {display: none } /* display is not removed after js function */
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <!-- button to toggle nav display -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleNav()">
        <div>toggleNav</div>
    </a><br>
    <nav id="nav">
        <h1>nav display</h1>
    </nav>
</div>

<p>Initially, @media width toggles nav display.</p>
<p>After running toggleNav() function, @media width does nothing.</p>
```

Apparently, CSS does not change display value after js changes it.

Is there some way for media max-width to change a display value after js changes it?

ANSWER:
The solution is to use js for all show and hide:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- based on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp -->
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>dropbtn</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <!-- button to toggle nav display -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleNav()">
        <div>toggleNav</div>
    </a><br>
    <nav>
        <h1>nav display</h1>
    </nav>
</div>

<p>Initially, @media width toggles nav display.</p>
<p>After running toggleNav() function, @media width does nothing.</p>

<script>
 /* toggle between showing and hiding nav when the user clicks on toggleNav */
 function toggleNav() {
     $("nav").toggle();
 }

 /* if narrow window, hide nav, if wide window show nav */
 function wideShowNav(x) {
     if (x.matches) {
         $("nav").hide();
     } else {
         $("nav").show();
     }
 }

 var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 70rem)")
 wideShowNav(x) // Call listener function at run time
 x.addListener(wideShowNav) // Attach listener function on state changes
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: JS add inline style which more specific. Consider toggling a class instead

Comment: When you change the css through js, you are setting rules inline, directly on the element. This will take priority over any block level rules, as it is last in the cascade.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35596887/8620333

Comment: I have an answer based on SpeedOfRound's comment.  I also changed the question so it is not a duplicate.  I will post the answer if the question is unmarked as duplicate.