# How to show/hide parts of a form based on if a checkbox is checked

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to show or hide form fields based on whether or not a checkbox is checked. I have no idea where to begin to make this work with eex.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :white_label, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= checkbox f, :white_label, class: "checkbox" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :white_label %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :logo, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :logo, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :logo %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :color, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :color, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :color %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using [`LiveView`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view) which I doubt, you should use javascript to interactively change the layout of the page.

`EEx` is a *server-side template rendering engine*. It produces HTML and sends it to the browser. That’s it.

Although one might use Ajax calls back to the server to re-render the page and re-send it back to the browser, usually this kind of tasks in solved on the client side, directly in the browser, with a help of javascript. Depending on what javascript library you prefer to use, the code for solutions is rather different, so you probably should look up the internets for *“show / hide elements on the page with javascript”* or like.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element) shows how it’s to be done with vanilla javascript.