# How to make divs appear and disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have on my ui following html elements

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="long"></p>Longitude<br>
<p id="lat"></p> Latitude<br>
<input type="text" id="ethaddress" placeholder="Enter your ETH address">
<button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>
```

when someone visits the site i only want to show the user the "try me" button.
once he clicks the "try me" button i want this button to dissapear and i want to show the elements with the id long, lat and ethaddress and the submit button

You find a link to an example here:
http://shiny-reaction.surge.sh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*
Now your issue is that in your js file your `getLocation()` function is defined as:

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
  //  x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
```

So that will not be hiding or showing anything, you need to update this.

In vanilla js, you could try this:

```js
function getLocation(btn){
  btn.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#form{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="getLocation(this)">Try It</button>
    
<form id="form">
  <p id="long"></p>Longitude<br>
  <p id="lat"></p> Latitude<br>
  <input type="text" id="ethaddress" placeholder="Enter your ETH address">
  <button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: its not working over here, i get no errors so i dont know why i cant get it to work

Comment: If you can show the full code, otherwise there is no way to tell, the snippet runs fine here in stack overflow.

Comment: i hosted it here on surge http://shiny-reaction.surge.sh

Comment: Please edit your post and add a minimum working example there.

Comment: i updated the post with the link, i cant ost a minimum working example cause i only see the try me button

Comment: i copied and pasted exactly the code from you and it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you want the elements to take up space you could go with `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;`. You set app an eventlistener to change the display property to block. You can do this in pure JS or Jquery with addClass.

Comment: `display: hidden` is not a valid css property

Comment: Right! sorry visibilty:hidden;