# showing/hiding html elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

which option among the following is better or used as a standard way to show/hide the html elements

1. changing element.style.display
2. adding/removing a separate class called hide {display: none}
3. any other standard way

PS: this [JavaScript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)  question uses the first option mentioned( changes the style to block to show which may not be desired). I would like to know whether this method is used in most websites or the adding /removing a separate class or any other way

3. A third way in the answers below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983509/14478972

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: this question uses the first option mentioned( changes the style to block to show which may not be desired). I would like to know whether this method is used in most websites or the adding /removing a separate class or any other way

Comment: For a better control it's preferably use of classes. This way you can hide multiple independent elements with simply adding/removing a class from a parent or even body itself.

Comment: yes, that looked a preferable way to me also @vanowm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to toggle a class using [`DOMTokenList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle):

> The `toggle()` method of the *DOMTokenList* interface removes a given token from the list and returns false. If token doesn't exist it's added and the function returns true.

Comment: so thats similar to the option 2- adding and removing a separate class

Comment: @Squiba, not really, as you have mentioned `{display: none}` in that option.

Comment: no  a separate class .hide { display: none} which can be toggled @Mamun

Comment: @Squiba, yes, in that case it is option 2.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 would be standard for only hiding the element, but if you would like to add other styles like transitions and pointer events option 2 is preferred

Answer (score 1):

Well except the first and second, there is the other way.
Which is rendering the element its self.

It has a better security. as the user wont know if there is a hidden element inside the toggle div. Eg when people try to look at the html

Have a look below

I used jQuery as its easier to write. If you are not able to rewrite a JavaScript version will be happy to rewrite for you.

```js
var items = $(".toggle");
var item = {};
// setup the auto toggle
$(".toggle").each(function(el) {
  var id = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds() + $(this).index()
  item[id] = $(this).find("content")
  if (!$(this).hasClass("show")){
  $(this).find("content").remove();
  }
   $(this).attr("id", id)
});

$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(this).find("content").length > 0)
    $(this).find("content").remove();
  else $(this).append(item[$(this).attr("id")])

  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  <h1>click here to toggle content </h1>
  <content>
    this is a test
  </content>
</div>

<div class="toggle show">
  <h1>click here to toggle content(start state is visible) </h1>
  <content>
    this is a test
  </content>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying. first to mention that I have never used jquery/ never seen any code with it.  So why user won't know that there is an hidden element inside the toggle div. the html is always visible ? @Alen.Toma

Comment: When you toggle a class, You only hide or show the element inside toggle with css. So when I for example click on f12 on chrome, I could see what is inside the toggle element. The option I provided remove and add the element it self, so for some reason you have a condition to show the element inside Then this is the best option as I as a user wont be able to see or edit the content inside the toggle element. Its all depends on what you would like to use and what is the used for.

Comment: ok, but anyway  content can always be seen from console @Alen.Toma

Comment: No, Ok try and see the element on the console. If you do not provide it then no it wont appear

Comment: ok, thats a good way to do things if needed