# how to hide/show elements

Tags: javascript, css

i have multiple divs i conviently id'd as "start", "a", "b", "c", ect. On page load i would like to show only the div id'd as "start". On the press of a button, i'd like to show only the div id'd as "a", and repeadtly continue through all the letters of the alphabet. heres the code i have so far.

```html
<div id="start">
  Lets Begin<br />
  <button id="startbutton">Start</button>
</div>

<div id="a">
  <img onclick="play('sounds/apple.mp3')" 
       src="images/apple.png" width="400" height="400" />
  <br />
  <button onclick="play('sounds/correct1.mp3')" 
          class="multiple-choice">
    Apple
  </button>
  <button onclick="play('sounds/wrong1.mp3')" 
          class="multiple-choice">
    Slinky
  </button>
  <button onclick="play('sounds/wrong1.mp3')" 
          class="multiple-choice">
    Orange
  </button>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <img onclick="" src="images/banana.png" 
       width="400" height="400" />
  <br />
  <button onclick="" class="multiple-choice">Monkey</button>
  <button onclick="" class="multiple-choice">Banana</button>
  <button onclick="" class="multiple-choice">Yellow</button>
</div>
```

im aware i should use addeventlistners rather than onclicks, but lets work with onclicks for now.

im quite new to javascript but have plenty of php experience. so i thought about switches with display:none, display:block styling. But i just cant peice it together.

Comment: Sidenote: [stop using on(...) attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers) for event handling. Bind your handlers on the JS side instead. As for how to hide things: defined a `hidden` class in your CSS, add it to everything that should start hidden, and then use JS to set ```element.classList.remove(`hidden`)``` whenever you need to unhide something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score -1):

That may be fairly easy to do so I'll try to have a quick and easy solution that get things done.

As already suggested in the comments above, it's a good idea to prepare a `CSS` class, let's name it `.hidden`, that simply sets the `display` property to `none` which means once applied to an element, it hides it.

So the idea is simple, we'll have some `div`s where each one contains a `button` that `shows` another `div` based on an `ID`. Let me explain the process further:

- Prepare the `.hidden` class as said above.
- We'll have some `div`s that can be shown or hidden based on `button`s clicks.
- We'll give those `div`s a class, let's name it `.toggleable` for example, which will make it easier for us to get select those `div`s later in the `JS` part.
- Those `div`s will by default have the `.hidden` class applied so they are hidden on initial page load. We'll only leave the `div#start` intact so it will be shown on page load.
- Each of those `div`s, as said, has a `button` that shows another `div` based on an `ID`. To easily grab those `button`s in the `JS` part we'll give each `button` a class, let's name it `.toggler`.
- Each `button` will also has a `data-*` attribute, let's name it `data-show` for example, that will hold the `ID` of the `div` to show (something like `data-show="a"`).
- Now we have the structure in place, we may move on to the implementation. In the `JS` part we'll select and cache all those `div`s and `button`s so we can easily work with them.
- We'll loop through the `button`s and apply a `click` event listener to each one that handles the showing/hiding of our `.togleable` `div`s.

  - The `click` handler will find the currently shown `.toggleable` `div` and hides it using our `.hidden` class.
  - And lastly, the handler will show the requested `.togleable` `div` based on the clicked `button`'s `data-show` attribute by removing the `.hidden` class from the requested `.togleable` `div`.

And now here's a live demo that you may manipulate the way you see fit your case:

```js
/** select all the DIVs and buttons */
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler'),
  /** quickly transform the result set retuned by "querySelectorAll" into an array so we can use the built-in array methods like "forEach" and "find" */
  togglebales = [...document.querySelectorAll('.toggleable')],
  /** "show" is our click event handler. It handles showing a DIV based on the ID found in the clicked button's "data-show" attribute. If you use an arrow function it won't work!! */
  show = function() {
    /** finds the currently shown DIV and hides it using the ".hhidden" class */
    togglebales.find(el => !el.classList.contains('hidden')).classList.add('hidden');
    /** finds the DIV to show by the ID in the button's "data-show" attribute (by simply removing the ".hidden" class from that DIV */
    togglebales.find(el => el.id === this.dataset.show).classList.remove('hidden');
  }

/** apply the click handler, "show", to the buttons */
togglers.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', show))
```

```css
/** hides an elemnt, simply. */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- The ".hidden" class is given to all ".togleable" DIVs except the one with ID of "start" so that one is shown on page load -->

<!-- Each button has a "data-show" atytribute that contains the ID of the DIV to show -->

<div class="toggleable" id="start">
  <p>Start DIV</p>
  <button class="toggler" data-show="a">Show DIV#a</button>
</div>
<div id="a" class="toggleable hidden">
  <p>DIV#a</p>
  <button class="toggler" data-show="b">Show DIV#b</button>
</div>
<div id="b" class="toggleable hidden">
  <p>DIV#b</p>
  <button class="toggler" data-show="c">Show DIV#c</button>
</div>
<div id="c" class="toggleable hidden">
  <p>DIV#c</p>
  <button class="toggler" data-show="start">Show DIV#start</button>
</div>
```

> The above solution is just one way of getting things done and it is NOT the only way nor the best way to do the job. Many other alternative solution can be found like using event delegation to reduce the call to the `addEventListener` method.

Finally, here are some useful links to the docs of some of the methods/techniques used in the snippet above: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`classList` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [`data attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [`array` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)